# How to prevent overlapping, but also keep the labels well-aligned

Tags: r, ggplot2

The graph shows Price towards Brands. Extra information on characteristics and price is provided on the labels, which makes them quite large and thus a cause for overlapping.

[image]

By using the function geom_label_repel, I was able to get the desired labels and fill each Brand with a color. It is important for me to keep the labels strictly to the x-axis, so I made use of "direction = 'y'".

The problem I have with the output is that the program is randomly placing the labels around the area in an inefficient way. For example, for GREEN, there are no obstacles to align 15, 21, 27 and 38 on the same row. Similarly for the other Brands/Colors.
Another issue is with the density. Consider PINK: there are many labels in approximately the same group, but they are very spread out. For instance, 14 can move 1 row down and be closer to 16, etc.

Overall, I want to edit the program to better organize the efficient layout of labels. What approaches can you suggest?

P.S. The usage of function geom_text_repel is not possible due to the impossibility of making the labels colorful.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
dataset <- June_2023_Product_portfolio_overview_sorted

brand_mobile_only_res <- rev(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F!", "G", "H", "I"))
mobile_only_res <- subset(dataset, HAS_INT == 'N' & HAS_DTV == 'N' & HAS_TEL == 'N' & HAS_MOB == 'Y' 
                          & Brand %in% brand_mobile_only_res) %>%
  distinct(Price_without_VAT, Minutes, .keep_all = TRUE)
ggplot(mobile_only_res, aes(x = Actual, y = Brand, fill = Brand)) +
  **geom_label_repel(aes(label = paste(Actual+5, "\n", Minutes, "/", Minutes, sep = "")), 
                   color = "white", size = 3.5, max.overlaps = 300, show.legend = FALSE, lineheight = 0.8, direction = 'y', box.padding = 0.001) +**
  scale_y_discrete(limits = brand_mobile_only_res) +
  xlab("Price (VAT included)") + ylab("Brand")
```